# SOAP call works on HTTP but not on HTTPS

Tags: http, security, soap, https

I have become a custodian of a very old set of clients that access a webservice hosted by one of our suppliers.

The dept. that used it stopped using it during COVID, and when the clients fired up the clients after COVID it had stopped working, well for this dept. anyway.

After investigation we found out that we could make the call on HTTP for the WSDL, but when HTTPS was invoked it would raise errors and end.

The main error it reports is a Security Problem

Other organisations report they can use it fine and no one is saying (admitting) to any changes.

The clients were written in VB6 Pro and Soap Toolkit3.0

There isn't much online about this, apart from load the WSDL manually, but we no longer have VB6 Pro to do any changes to do this so I am hoping someone recognises the issue i.e., networking, security, ssl, tls (insert any other grab at straw term).

This is the last ditch attempt to get it working before we let them know they ahve to re-write it in something else

Comment: I don't know anything about SOAP and VB but the first idea that comes into my mind is an expired certificate. Do you have any info about the certificate validity ?

Comment: HI Cheers for commenting. We have checked out certificates etc., and nothing, it still gives the same errors :(

Comment: Just for completeness. We found another Org within our greater Org unit that had the same problem. It appeared after they moved from server 2008 to 2019, it looks like there may be something causing the issue there.

I noticed that there was a fix for SOAP (but I don't know what for) but can't find it anywhere either, old old old....

Have sent recommendation to re-write in  .NET